# Is there any solution to get loaded time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://pythonbasics.org')
timeout = 3
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'main'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
finally:
    print("Page loaded")
```

This is my code , i want to get wait time , for example if It took 1 minute to load some xpath class get this time

Comment: Do you want to get page rendering time or time to locate element on page?

Comment: time to locate element

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://pythonbasics.org')
timeout = 100

try:
    start_time = time.time()
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'main'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    diff_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("It takes {} seconds to find element".format(diff_time))

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
finally:
    print("Page loaded")
```

Comment: @user15528966 what do you mean by *unrealistic*?

Comment: @user15528966 it gives me ~0.02 seconds. Page doesn't contain any (or at least complicated) JavaScript, so everything seem to be OK

Comment: Ii want to test if slide loaded successfully, some times slider slow loaded ..... is it good idea ? to check with xpath ?

Comment: @user15528966 what is "slider"? Do you still mean [this page](https://pythonbasics.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @jaSON is correct. But there is an another alternative which is `timeit`  method from python library timeit.
There are various ways in which you could use it.
I'll give you the hyperlink for properly explained article.
[Python Timit()]: [https://www.guru99.com/timeit-python-examples.html#:~:text=Python%20timeit()%20is%20a,given%20set%20of%20code%20snippets.](https://www.guru99.com/timeit-python-examples.html#:%7E:text=Python%20timeit()%20is%20a,given%20set%20of%20code%20snippets.)